# C#. Count Consecutive 1 bits in ulong

Tags: c#

Basically i want to count the number of consecutive 1 bits (1 bit groups) in a ulong. for example:
ulong x = 0x1BD11BDAA9FC1A22UL;
In binary it becomes: 1101111010001000110111101101010101001111111000001101000100010.
I need output as No of consecutive 1 bits = 16.

Comment: Errr clarify... consecutive means they follow each other. What you seem to need or want is some sort of checksum.

Comment: 110111 implies consective 1 bits = 2, 110111011 implies consecutive 1 bits = 3,  i want the 'count of 1 bit groups'.

Comment: `bitcount(x&~(x<<1))`

Comment: `Regex.Matches( "1101111010001000110111101101010101001111111000001101000100010",  "1(?=1)" ).Count` how about just converting your number to a string and applying a regex against it.

Answer (score 4):

Convert to bitstring, split at `0` character while removing empty entries, count the number of groups.

```
static void Main()
{
    long x = 0x1BD11BDAA9FC1A22; 
    var bitstring = Convert.ToString(x, 2) ;    
    Console.WriteLine("Bitstring: " + bitstring);
    var oneBitGroups = bitstring.Split(new char[]{'0'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length;
    Console.WriteLine("The number of 1 bit groups is: " + oneBitGroups);
}
```

Output:

```
Bitstring: 1101111010001000110111101101010101001111111000001101000100010                                                                                                                                                                      
The number of 1 bit groups is: 16
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with bitshift and counting each time the least significant bit is 1 and the previous wasn't.

```
public static int BitGroupCount(long num)
{
    int count = 0;
    bool prevOne = false;
    while (num != 0)
    {
        bool currOne = (num & 1) == 1;
        if (currOne && !prevOne)
            count++;
        num = num >> 1;
        prevOne = currOne;
    }

    return count;
}
```

If you run

```
Console.WriteLine(BitGroupCount((long)0x1BD11BDAA9FC1A22UL));
```

You will get 16 as the result

Answer (score 0):

Something like [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0ff76c9a-8d8c-46f3-94cc-420f719a14e4/how-to-convert-floatdoubleulong-into-binaryotcalhex-string?forum=netfxbcl) to get the value as a binary string then :

```
int consecutive = 0;
char? previous = null;
foreach (char c in str)
{
    if (previous != null)
    {
        if (previous.Equals('1') && c.Equals('1'))
        {
            consecutive++;
        }
    }
    previous = c;
}
return consecutive;
```

Comment: i am using something like this, but i need my code to be faster. any solns using bitshift operations.

Comment: Why the vote down? This is a perfectly legitimate answer and you never mentioned that you had a solution like this in place already

Comment: @BarryO'Kane I didn't downvote (in fact, once you correct it, I'll upvote to compensate), but `char` should be `char?`, `c.Equals(1)` should be `c.Equals('1')`, and `previous = c` should be out of the `if(previous != null)` block, or else it'll never get a value and `previous` will always be `null`

Comment: There you go, +1 to compensate the unfair downvote

Comment: You're dead right @Jcl, amended now. The previous comment was directed at the OP.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
ulong x = 0x1BD11BDAA9FC1A22UL;
bool last = false;
int count = 0;
for(int i = sizeof(ulong)*8-1; i >= 0; i--)
{
  var c = x & (1UL<<i);
  if(c != 0 && !last)
    count ++;
  last = c != 0;
}
```

`count` should be `16`

Answer (score 0):

I think i found the solution based on [Hamming Weight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight) (thanks to PetSerAl):

```
public static int no_of_consecutive_one_bits(ulong x)
{
    x = (x & ~(x << 1));
    x -= (x >> 1) & 0x5555555555555555;
    x = (x & 0x3333333333333333) + ((x >> 2) & 0x3333333333333333);
    x = (x + (x >> 4)) & 0x0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f;
    return ((int)((x * 0x0101010101010101) >> 56)); 
}
```

Some explanation: The `x & ~(x<<1)` is basically isolating the last bit in each "group".  The rest is the Hamming Weight algorithm for summing the number of non-zero bits.